# nesting components with createElement in React yields error

Tags: reactjs, typescript, error-handling, components, jsx

I'm trying to create a helper function that nest a passed element/component as a children of itself of several depths.

So something like this

```js
const Chain = nested(4, () => <div />)
return (
  <Chain />
)
```

Should render divs nested 4 levels

```js
<div>
  <div>
    <div>
      <div />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I implemented the function in React like this.

```js
/** nest the given element in itself of specified depth */
export const nested = (
  depth: number,
  element: () => JSX.Element
): FC<any> => () => {

  let chain = element();
  for (let i = 0; i < depth; i++) {
    chain = React.createElement(
      element().type,
      element().props,
      chain
    );
  }
  return chain;
};
```

It renders and displays the nested Divs correctly, but gives back an error message i don't understand how to correct.

```
Warning: Functions are not valid as a React child. This may happen if you return a Component instead of <Component /> from render. Or maybe you meant to call this function rather than return it.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try going with a `recursive` solution.

```
const createInnerElements = (count, childElement) => {
   if (count == 1) {
     return <div>{childElement}</div>
   }
   return createInnerElements(count - 1, <div>{childElement}</div>);
}

// in your parent component,
return <>{createInnerElements(4, <></>)}</>
```

Comment: Thanks! I modified this solution to make the element type dynamic and posted it below.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I settled with. Credit to @senthil balaji's answer.

```js
export const NestedTags = (depth: number, childElement: JSX.Element): JSX.Element => {
  if (depth === 1) {
    return (
      <childElement.type {...childElement.props}>
        {childElement}
      </childElement.type>
    );
  }

  return NestedTags(
    depth - 1,
    <childElement.type {...childElement.props}>
      {childElement}
    </childElement.type>
  );
};
```

and should be wrapped in a React Fragment using used in parent.

```js
<>
  {NestedTags(5, <div className='segment'><div>)}
</>
```

The caveat for this is that it can't nest when passed a React Component Type like so:

```js
const Test = ({className}: {className: string}) => (
  <a className={className}>hello</a>;
)
//...
return (
  <>
    {NestedTags(5, <Test className='test'/>}
  </>
)};
```